# Add Custom attribute from Sales_Order table into New order email template?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have create new custom attribute on Sales_order table name "QR_Code". How to insert this field into my new order email template?

Thanks
kllee

Comment: You need to first save into order table using sales order place before event then you will get into email

Answer (score 0):

Please Orverride the following file

```
/var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/order.php
```

and and your custom variable value here near by 1336 line number.

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
     'order'        => $this,
     'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
     'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
     'custom_var' => 'custom_value'
));
```

After this add this variable in your new_order template.

```
app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new_guest.html
```

and add like this `{{var custom_var}}`

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Sorry, I follow up on Magento 2.

Comment: it's working fine?

Comment: I tested in M1 not sure about M2

Answer (score 0):

To send extra field in order email you need to do the following,

1. Over ride the email template file in custom extension like this.

   app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\sales_email_order_items.xml

Add following code in above file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="items">
            <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::email/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. Create a new template file `items.phtml` in your template folder as this.

   ```
   app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\email\items.phtml

   <?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
   <h3><?= $_order->getYOURFIELD(); ?></h3>    

   <?php if ($_order): ?>
       <?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
   <table class="email-items">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th class="item-info">
                   <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items'); ?>
               </th>
               <th class="item-qty">
                   <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty'); ?>
               </th>
               <th class="item-price">
                   <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price'); ?>
               </th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
           <?php
               if ($_item->getParentItem()) {
                   continue;
               }
           ?>
           <tbody>
               <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
           </tbody>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
       <tfoot class="order-totals">
           <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
       </tfoot>
   </table>
   <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
       <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
       <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
           <br />
           <table class="message-gift">
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                       <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:'); ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                       <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:'); ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                       <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:'); ?></strong>
                       <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo your custom attribute like this way i was call on switch condition, you can use according to your requirements.

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('brand'); ?>

OR

<?php
 $brandname = $_product->getAttributeText('brand');
 if (trim($brandname)) {
   echo "" .$this->htmlEscape($brandname);
 }
?>
```